# クイックソートにおけるデータ列のソートの仕方について

Tags: アルゴリズム

はじめまして。
アルゴリズム初心者でクイックソートでつまづいております。

{5,3,2,6,4,1,3,7}というデータ列で、真ん中の4を基準値（ピボット）とした場合（6と4の間にパーテーションを設けた場合、）どのように(昇順)ソートされていくか順を追ってご説明頂けますと幸いです。
※自分で試した場合、なぜか昇順でソートすることができませんでした。（１が最左端に来ず、並び順が{3,3,2,1,:4,6,5,7}となりました。）

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

疑似コードは以下の通りです。

```
QUICKSORT(,,)
1 if <
2      then  ← PARTITION(, ,)
3               QUICKSORT(,,)
4               QUICKSORT(, +1,)

PARTITION(,,)
1  ← []
2  ←  -1
3  ← +1
4 while TRUE
5          do repeat  ← -1
6                until [] ≤ 
7                repeat  ← +1
8                until [] ≥ 
9                if < 
10                   then 値を交換する [] ← []
11                   else return
```

ソートの記述例は以下のとおりです。
前提： ← []を一つ目の要素5とした。

step1 (i)5,3,2,6,:4,1,3,7(j)　#:はパーテーションを意味する。

step2 **5(i)**,3,2,6,:4,1,**3(j)**,7  # iがjより小さいのでj--

step3 **3(i)**,3,2,6,:4,1,**5(j)**,7　# i>jなのでiとjをswap

step4 3,3,2,**6(i)**,:4,1,**5(j)**,7　# a[i]≥5となるまでi++

step5 3,3,2,**6(i)**,:4,**1(j)**,5,7  # iがjより小さいのでj--

step6 3,3,2,**1(i)**,:4,**6(j)**,5,7  # i>jなのでiとjをswap

step7 3,3,2,**1(i)**,:**4(j)**,6,5,7  # iがjより小さいのでj--

step8 3,3,2,1,:**4(j)**,**6(i)**,5,7 # a[i]≥5となるまでi++

j>iとなったのでループ終了。

Comment: できれば実際に試してうまくいかなかったコードを提示してもらった方が具体的なアドバイスが付きやすいと思います。

Comment: ここでいう「自分で試した」というのは、ご自身で手でやってみて上手くいかなかったということでしょうか？　そうでしたら、試された際の記録を質問文に追記頂ければと思います。

Comment: 自身のソートの記録を本文に追加いたしました。

Comment: 参考: [Understanding Quicksort (with interactive demo)](http://me.dt.in.th/page/Quicksort/)

Comment: `{3,3,2,1,:4,6,5,7}`というのは`PARTITION`を終えた直後の状態ですね。クイックソートの途中の状態としては正しいかと。疑似コードでは`QUICKSORT(,,)`, `QUICKSORT(, +1,)`と続くので、ソートを完了するためにはそれらも実行する必要があります。